# Integer Solutions to $x + y + z = 3$, $xy + yz + xz + 2xyz = 2017$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to find integer solutions to $x + y + z = 3$, $xy + yz + xz + 2xyz = 2017$.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: this has been asked before but for some reason I can't find it.

Comment: Current contest question. Don't answer.

Comment: I thought you said it ended today or something

Comment: It says to submit solutions by Friday Jan 20th. So I'm not completely sure.

Comment: try $$x=47,y=-1,z=-43$$

Comment: I doubt they are asking such a question for personal benefit, when the account has asked 5 contest questions in the past 20 hours. Why are people giving solutions?

Comment: @Kaynex How can one remove an answer and have it put back at a later date?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut:  You can delete an answer.  When I do it stays in the system and I (and other users with lots of rep) still see it.  You can then undelete it when you want, but you have to remember to do so.

Answer (score 0):

let $xyz = a$, then the polynom with the roots (x, y, z)  is

$t^3 - 3t^2 + (2017-2*a)t - a$

$t^3 - 3t^2 + (2017-2*a)t - a = 0 $  => $t^3 - 3t^2 + 2017t = a(2t+1)$

Try to find the integer solutions.
t = 0 => a=0;

else 
$t$  is coptime to $2t+1$ => $2t+1 | t^2 - 3t + 2017$ => $2t+1 | 2t^2 - 6t + 4034$ => $2t+1|7t - 4034$ => $2t+1|14t-8068$ => $2t+1|8075$

So, we can find small set of possible values of t, from it get small set of possible values of a, and solve the some systems like x+y+z = 3, xy+xz +zy = 2017-2a, xyz = a